# How to get my role in application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it posible to get my role from my application, having my user **access_token**?

Comment: Do you mean as a developer/tester etc? There is a connection of appliactionsdeveloper on user https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ but it only lists your apps not the specific role. It doesn't require extra permissions though https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fapplications%2Fdeveloper

Comment: Also there's https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles but that requires an APP access token

Comment: Yes yes! I making an admin panel for game. And i need to get role (Admin,Developer,Testes) using user access_token

Comment: Then I suggest you look at the link above then and an app access token can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ for your app

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/

But be aware its Beta